# Swig Ruby "TypeError: Expected argument 0 of type int *, but got Fixnum 0"

Tags: c, ruby, swig

It's been a while since I used Swig, so this is probably some dumb mistake.

I used swig to create the interface for a set of functions,  but something is not right.  For example when I try to call a function that expected a (int *) in c, I get the above error.  Any thoughts as to what I am doing wrong?

I ran using swig 2.0.11-1ubuntu2

```
swig -ruby -module itkDB  itkDB.i
```

My interface file was

```
%module itkDB 
%{
#include "itkDB.h"
%}
// with an included copy of the itkDB.h file
```

The header contains the following declaration:

```
CDS_EXTERN_C String
dbiInit(int *pArgc,
    char    *pArgv[]);
```

I get the above error when I try this from an irb session:

```
ItkDB.dbInit 0, "blah"
```

the generated wrapper function looks like this:

```
SWIGINTERN VALUE
_wrap_dbiInit(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE self) {
  int *arg1 = (int *) 0 ;
  char **arg2 ;
  void *argp1 = 0 ;
  int res1 = 0 ;
  void *argp2 = 0 ;
  int res2 = 0 ;
  String result;
  VALUE vresult = Qnil;

  if ((argc < 2) || (argc > 2)) {
    rb_raise(rb_eArgError, "wrong # of arguments(%d for 2)",argc); SWIG_fail;
  }
  res1 = SWIG_ConvertPtr(argv[0], &argp1,SWIGTYPE_p_int, 0 |  0 );
  if (!SWIG_IsOK(res1)) {
    SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(res1), Ruby_Format_TypeError( "", "int *","dbiInit", 1, argv[0] )); 
  }
  arg1 = (int *)(argp1);
  res2 = SWIG_ConvertPtr(argv[1], &argp2,SWIGTYPE_p_p_char, 0 |  0 );
  if (!SWIG_IsOK(res2)) {
    SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(res2), Ruby_Format_TypeError( "", "char *[]","dbiInit", 2, argv[1] )); 
  } 
  arg2 = (char **)(argp2);
  result = (String)dbiInit(arg1,arg2);
  vresult = SWIG_FromCharPtr((const char *)result);
  return vresult;
fail:
  return Qnil;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As expected this was a simple problem.  The following added to the interface file fixed the problem.  It turned out this was one of the few cases were the library actually did want a reference to an integer.
The *INPUT tells swig to allow a normal integer to be passed to the function,  it then creates a reference to that passed integer and sends that to the function.

```
CDS_EXTERN_C String
dbiInit(int *INPUT,
    char    *pArgv[]);
```